# How to cycle through MySQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql, rows, cycle, records

I am trying to achieve a web PHP program that will display data from a records in a MySQL database in a HTML form. I have a couple of navigation buttons that I wish to cycle to the next and previous records in the database.

My problem is, I can't seem to cycle back and forth through the records. mysql_fetch_assoc just gets one row or is only good when it comes to a while loop.

Any help would be appreciated!
This is what I have so far...

```
    $page = intval($_GET['page']);

    $limitStart = $page - 1;
    if($limitStart < 0) {
        $limitStart = 0;
    }

    $query = "SELECT caleadID, region, siteaddr1, siteaddr2, siteaddr3, siteaddr4, sitepcode, ";
    $query .= "addgennotes, description, value, award, awardaddr1, awardaddr2, awardaddr3, awardaddr4, awardpcode, ";
    $query .= "phone_number, fax_number, fldAwardedWebsite, fldAwardedEmail, contact_name, date FROM tblTradesman_Awarded WHERE 1";
    $query .= ' LIMIT ' . $limitStart . ',2';
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($result);

    $result_array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result_array[] = $row;
    }
    if(intval($page) === 0) {
        $previousRecord = NULL;
        $currentRecord = $result_array[0];
        $nextRecord = $result_array[1];
    } else {
        $previousRecord = $result_array[0];
        $currentRecord = $result_array[1];
        $nextRecord = $result_array[2]; 
    }
    if($previousRecord) {

    }

    if($nextRecord) {

}
?>
<?PHP
    $caleadID = $currentRecord['caleadID'];
    $region = $currentRecord['region'];
    $siteaddr1 = $currentRecord['siteaddr1'];
    $siteaddr2 = $currentRecord['siteaddr2'];
    $siteaddr3 = $currentRecord['siteaddr3'];
    $siteaddr4 = $currentRecord['siteaddr4'];
    $sitepcode = $currentRecord['sitepcode'];
    $addgennotes = $currentRecord['addgennotes'];
    $description = $currentRecord['description'];
    $value = $currentRecord['value'];
    $award = $currentRecord['award'];
    $awardaddr1 = $currentRecord['awardaddr1'];
    $awardaddr2 = $currentRecord['awardaddr2'];
    $awardaddr3 = $currentRecord['awardaddr3'];
    $awardaddr4 = $currentRecord['awardaddr4'];
    $awardpcode = $currentRecord['awardpcode'];
    $phone_number = $currentRecord['phone_number'];
    $fax_number = $currentRecord['fax_number'];
    $fldAwardedWebsite = $currentRecord['fldAwardedWebsite'];
    $fldAwardedEmail = $currentRecord['fldAwardedEmail'];
    $contact_name = $currentRecord['contact_name'];
    $date = $currentRecord['date'];

?>

<div id="tradesmen_data">
    <div id="primary">
        <label for="caleadID">Tradesman Lead ID: </label>
        <input type="text" name="caleadID" value="<?PHP echo $caleadID ?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="value">Job Value GBP: </label>
        <input type="text" name="value" value="<?PHP echo $value ?>" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="date">Tradesman Publish Date: </label>
        <input type="text" name="date" value="<?PHP echo $date ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        <fieldset id="Site">
            <legend>Site Details</legend>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="siteaddr1">Site Address: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="siteaddr1" value="<?PHP echo $siteaddr1 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="siteaddr2" value="<?PHP echo $siteaddr2 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>            
                <dt><label></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="siteaddr3" value="<?PHP echo $siteaddr3 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>            
                <dt><label></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="siteaddr4" value="<?PHP echo $siteaddr4 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>            
                <dt><label for="sitepcode">Postcode: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="sitepcode" value="<?PHP echo $sitepcode ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>            
                <dt><label for="region">Region: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="region" value="<?PHP echo $region ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>                
                <dt><label for="addgennotes">General Notes: </label></dt>
                <dd><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="addgennotes"><?PHP echo $addgennotes ?></textarea></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>            
                <dt><label for="description">Description: </label></dt>
                <dd><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="description"><?PHP echo $description ?></textarea></dd>
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">
        <fieldset id="Contractor">
            <legend>Contractor Details</legend>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="award">Awarded To: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="award" value="<?PHP echo $award ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="awardaddr1">Address: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="awardaddr1" value="<?PHP echo $awardaddr1 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="awardaddr2" value="<?PHP echo $awardaddr2 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="awardaddr3" value="<?PHP echo $awardaddr3 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label></label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="awardaddr4" value="<?PHP echo $awardaddr4 ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="awardpcode">Postcode: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="awardpcode" value="<?PHP echo $awardpcode ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="phone_number">Telephone: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="phone_number" value="<?PHP echo $phone_number ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="fax_number">Fax: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="fax_number" value="<?PHP echo $fax_number ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="fldAwardedWebsite">Website: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="fldAwardedWebsite" value="<?PHP echo $fldAwardedWebsite ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="fldAwardedEmail">Email: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="fldAwardedEmail" value="<?PHP echo $fldAwardedEmail ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="contact_name">Contact Name: </label></dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="contact_name" value="<?PHP echo $contact_name ?>" /></dd>
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
        <?PHP
            $contact_made = true;
            if ($contact_made) {
                echo "<div id=\"contact_made\">";
                echo "Contact has been made";
                echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clear_float"></div>
</div>
<div id="tradesmen_data_navigation">
    <a href="#"><input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous Record" /></a>
    <a href="#"><input type="submit" name="view_lead" value="Generate Lead" /></a>
    <a href="#"><input type="submit" name="next" value="Next Record" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I cycle through the rows with Limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is untested, but it should point you into the right direction.

The GET parameter `page` controls which section of the result set to show as you set the `LIMIT` of the query using the value of `page`.

You select the current record from DB as well as the previous and the next. This way, you know if you can generate a link to the next/previous record in your application.

```
$page = intval($_GET['page']);

$limitStart = $page - 1;
if($limitStart < 0) {
    $limitStart = 0;
}

$query = "SELECT caleadID, region, siteaddr1, siteaddr2, siteaddr3, siteaddr4, sitepcode, ";
$query .= "addgennotes, description, value, award, awardaddr1, awardaddr2, awardaddr3, awardaddr4, awardpcode, ";
$query .= "phone_number, fax_number, fldAwardedWebsite, fldAwardedEmail, contact_name, date FROM tblTradesman_Awarded WHERE 1";
$query .= ' LIMIT ' . $limitStart . ',3';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
confirm_query($result);
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $result_array[] = $row;
}

if(intval($page) === 0) {
    $previousRecord = NULL;
    $currentRecord = $result_array[0];
    $nextRecord = $result_array[1];
} else {
    $previousRecord = $result_array[0];
    $currentRecord = $result_array[1];
    $nextRecord = $result_array[2]; 
}

if($previousRecord) {
    $prevPage = $page - 1;
    if($prevPage < 0) {
        $pagePage = 0;
    }

    echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . $prevPage . '">previous</a>';
}

if($nextRecord) {
    echo '<a href="index.php?page=' . ($page + 1) . '">next</a>';
}
```

Comment: I only need 1 row at a time, as one row contains all the information for the form. The form only displays one row of information at a time

Comment: I think I understand it now, but how can I get the buttons to jump to the next set of records?

Comment: Just add a link/button or whatever to your HTML output and make sure to pass the parameter `page`. I updated the code again.

Comment: IT WORKS, thanks ever so much. One issue though, it gets stuck at the second record (page=1)

Comment: Sorry, the limit should be page,3. I updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through your array.

By returning mysqli_fetch_assoc you effectively return a single row.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $returningRows[] = $row;
}

return $returningRows;
```

Comment: I wish to use buttons to cycle through, won't that keep looping through?

Comment: @Rubixryan, the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function does the incrementing for you, and the statement will return false once the result runs out of rows, so the loop will stop.

Comment: @slynagh, how would I control it with buttons?

Comment: Hi all, sorry was busy so missed responses. @Rubixryan you can use either POST or GET values to control your query. So for example your next button will fire the user to index.php?start=10 and you can modify your query to use LIMIT 10, 10 which will return 10 rows starting from row 10.